# Cross domain across three domains and two UA

Tags: google-analytics, cross-domain, google-tag-manager

this is my first post here, hoping to find a solution and learn from each other.

I have some problems setting up cross-domain tracking using GTM. Website 1 and Website 2 uses different UAs and different container on GTM.

www.website1.com - UA1, GTM1

www.website2.com - - UA2, GTM2
subdomain.website2.com
(these two sites already have a working cross domain with payment completing in subdomain.website2.com, At the moment there are several goals on UA2 of website2 + subdomain.website2 and they are all working fine.)

So what i did is fire UA1 GA tag on website 2 on all pages using GTM1, with allow linker.

The journey I am trying to set up the cross domain are as below:

Journey 1
www.website1.com >>> www.website2.com >>>subdomain.website2.com

Journey 2 
www.website1.com >>> subdomain.website2.com

Now i want to set up Goals on UA1 to check conversion of Journey 1 and Journey 2. Even though I've tested those two journeys on Tag assistant recording and also Real Time view on GA the goals are simply not working.

Anyone can help with me.

Thank you so much.
Poovan

Comment: Cross domain tracking with Universal Analytics does not work across properties.

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain tracking can work on the same property but not across. If you are interested on the matter here is out guru: https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/troubleshooting-cross-domain-tracking-in-google-analytics/

Hope it helps.